# 'touchstart', 'touchend', 'touchmove' added to body, check if element is image

Tags: javascript, html, events, touch

We have a use case where we need to catch the touch start, end and move events - but, as the feed is constantly updated, we cannot just keep adding the event to every div that is added as they come into the feed. So, instead, we added the event listeners to the BODY itself. Yet, while normally I would do something like `$(event.target).is("img")` for example, to see if the target that is being touched/moved is an image, it doesn't seem to work when it is attached to the body or document element.

I want to avoid having to attach this listener directly to each element being added to the feed, as that'd slow things down unnecessarily; having it on the body/document level is far better because then any item added will be processed, regardless of when it was added (as the listener is on the top level element).

The problem is that even if I use `currentTarget` or `target` or even any of the get positions or closest, it doesn't ever seem to return that it's on an image.

Am curious if y'all have any ideas on that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was finally able to figure it out:

```
let changedTouch = event.changedTouches[0];
elem = document.elementFromPoint(changedTouch.clientX, changedTouch.clientY);

  if (elem.tagName === 'IMG') {
    ...do whatever...
  }
```

Doing it this way, I'm able to scale the images, or do whatever I want with them, even if they are added to the DOM as the user scrolls down, dynamically added by the system, or even removed and moved up.

Still working on a way to actually reset the image back to it's original state once done lol but hey, at least this works!